cowsay path not working
I've been trying to add custom ASCII art to cowsay
Following a tutorial, i've created a .cowsay/cowfiles path in my home directory and put a file called cow2.cow that's just a copy of the original default.cow found in /usr/share/cowsay/cowfiles. As described in the manual for the command, i then added my custom cows folder to the relevant path variable in my shell file:
COWPATH=$COWPATH:$HOME/.cowsay/cowfiles
However, this doesn't work, and when i use ... | cowsay -f cow2 it tells me it couldn't find the cow file. It does work if i specify the whole path though: ... | cowsay -f $HOME/.cowsay/cowpath/cow2.cow
How do I fix this?
EDIT: I forgot to export the new COWSAY path. This is an environment variable, not a shell variable
The correct line to add to the path is export COWSAY=$COWSAY:<additional path>

more detail required: How did you install cowsay, which tutorial...

apologies, the mistake was not in the installation but in how i was trying to append my new path to the original one

The COWSAY path is an environment variable, not a shell variable.
Adding
export COWPATH=$COWPATH:<additional path>

to my .bashrc fixed the problem
